# Load web workers dynamically. Errors resolving relative imports

Tags: javascript, blob, web-worker

**Context:**

I am loading several web workers in a dynamic way by using blob-based URIs. In my problem, this strategy is required because workers' content is partially generated using a template-based solution. See (1) in code

**Problem:**

Web workers include `import` sentences with relative paths. As they are loaded using the `Worker` constructor and it does not allow to specify a base path, relative imports cannot be properly resolved as absolute references. As a result, the worker loading process fails with no console message (I guess a 404 error is under the hood).

**Example:**

In this example we have created the following set of resources:

```
index.html
/scripts
  /helpers
     helper.x.js
     helper.y.js
  /loader
     loader.js
  /workers
     worker.x.js
```

We have created a dynamic loader in loader.js:

```
function Loader () {

  function asCode (text) { ... }

  async function load (path) {
    let response = await fetch (path)
    let text     = await response.text ()
    let code     = asCode (text) // (1)
    let blob     = new Blob ([code], { type: 'text/javascript' })
    let url      = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    let worker   = new Worker (url, { type: 'module' })
    return worker
  }

  return { load }
}

export default Loader ()
```

The worker in worker.x.js imports two naive helpers X & Y by using relative paths. Please, notice that if the path in import sentences where absolute (http://...) the problem described here would not appear:

```
  import X from '../helpers/helper.x.js'
  import Y from '../helpers/helper.y.js'

  X.fx ()
  Y.fy ()
```

Finally, in index.html we load the worker:

```
<body>
   <script type="module">
     import Loader from './scripts/loader/loader.js'
     let WX = Loader.load ('./scripts/workers/worker.x.js')
   </script>
</body>
```

Please, visit this [replit](https://replit.com/@javiervelezreyes/Dynamic-Web-Workers) to explore the project.

**Question:**

Is there any way to load web worker scripts in a dynamic way specifying the base path that must be used to resolve relative paths in inner import sentences? For me, an extension of the Worker constructor with a new `base` parameter like this would be perfect :)

```
let WX = new Worker (path, { type: 'module', base: 'the-base-path' })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your `asCode` method to also inject the base URI.

In your template, insert a marker in front of your relative URLs that you'll replace at the time of building your blob.
To get the "fake" base URL as an absolute one, you can check the `Response` object you get from `fetch()` and extract the directory path from its `.url` property.

Now, your "dynamic" module imports absolute paths and everyone is happy:
`loader.js`

```js
function Loader () {

  function asCode (text, baseURI) {
    return baseURI
      ? text.replace(/\$base_url\$/g, baseURI)
      : text;
  }
  
  async function load (path) {
    let response = await fetch (path)
    let text     = await response.text ()
    let absolute = response.url;
    // remove the worker script's file name to get its base URI
    let href     = absolute.substring(0, absolute.lastIndexOf('/'));
    let code     = asCode (text, href)
    let blob     = new Blob ([code], {type: 'text/javascript' })
    let url      = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    let worker   = new Worker (url, { type: 'module' })
    return worker
  }

  return { load }
}

export default Loader ()
```

And *worker.x.js* now looks like

```js
import X from '$base_url$/../helpers/helper.x.js'
import Y from '$base_url$/../helpers/helper.y.js'

X.fx ()
Y.fy ()
```

[Updated repl.it.](https://replit.com/@Kaiido/Dynamic-Web-Workers)

Comment: Easy-peasy Kaiido. I recognize that this idea came to my mind but it was rapidly discarded because I wrongly assumed that I would require to visit all the import dependencies recursively in order to totally solve the problem but as you propose, just by changing the import in the source worker it's enough. Thanx ;)